# Is G1GC stable for Large spark application

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc

Our data pipeline is currently running on Spark 2.4 and java version 1.8, it takes about 10 hours to performing all the ETL steps.

Currently we noticed that driver memory heap is elevated and causing a lot of full GCs toward the end of pipeline( the heap is given 70G ), even with all the full GCs, the heap stays at the highest level, pls keep in mind this is the spark driver.

We are currently using -XX:+UseParallelGC, after testing with -XX:+UseG1GC. We noticed that the number of full GC came down a lot, hence thinking to change to G1GC. But I heard from colleague that G1GC is not stable few years back, wondering is G1GC is stable GC now for large Spark application ( in our case, running 10+ hour, 50G+ heap size)

Answer (score 0):

(this was a comment that grew)

First off, it sounds like you have a memory leak.Just from your description, it sounds like you're not freeing old gen. Moving over to G1 will not fix that.

Note that I'm not familiar with your particular use-case nor do I know if there's any latency requirements. 
Having said that, we have instances running J8 with g1 and 800 GB (sometimes larger, record is 1.5 TB) heaps without any major issues.
 Note that, that at these kind of heap sizes, weird edge cases can occur and the configuration can be fragile. But it is used in production.
 One take away we have is that the number of HW threads are vitally important. Even if they don't do anything  most of the time, once the gc moves into mixed cycles, the number of hw thread becomes exceedingly important.

Generally speaking, if this is a batch style application without latency requirements, stay with the parallel collector and fix the memory leak. G1 consumes cpu concurrently and the parallel collector does not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This high memory issue we are facing is on the driver. Only thing we are seeing can cause this is that we have many queries that leverage broadcast join for performance. It appears that broadcasted dataset stayed on driver heap even after the query with broadcast join completes. It maybe due to due to spark resiliency but i am wondering if there is way to force this broadcasted dataset to be GCed

Comment: You need to find a way to make the driver let the retained objects go, simple as that. That is more properly a Spark question and not a gc question.